# Does the percentage value refer to the width of the containing block?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

We can set the padding and margin properties of an element E using either pixels or percentages.

A) I assume that when we use percentages, the percentage value refers to the width of  the containing block? Thus, if E is declared directly inside `<body>` element, then the containing block is `<body>` and percentage value refers to  width of `<body>`element.

B) What is the default width of a `<body>`element?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

If I set E’s padding to 50%:

```
   #E
   {
      padding: 50%;
   }
```

then the width of E's *"padding-left + padding-right"* will equal the width of a viewport (when viewport is expanded over the entire screen).

A) Thus, I assume the width (specified in pixels) of `<body>` depends on a horizontal resolution of a monitor and the width of a viewport? My screen resolution is set to 1024*768, and thus in my case the width of a `<body>` is 1024px (assuming viewport is expanded over the entire screen) ? But if I was to change the resolution to 800*600, then the width of a `<body>` would be 800px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the CSS will be applied to the element containing it.
2. The default width in percentages for the `<body>` tag is 100%.

In general, you should be using a CSS file linked to your HTML, and use [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) to chose what elements to style. It is bad practice to embed CSS into your HTML, as this is not very maintainable (i.e. if you need to change the style across a website).

**Edit:**

```
#E { padding: 50%; }
```

is a shortcut to:

```
#E { padding-top: 50%; padding-right: 50%; padding-left: 50%; padding-bottom: 50%;}
```

In regards to what the % stand for, it's viewport width, i.e. the number of pixels in the inner browser window, showing the HTML, nothing to do with your screen resolution.

If you were to change your window resolution to 800px*600px your viewport width would be somewhat less than 800px, as the scrollbar takes up some of that.

Comment: hi, in case you find the time ... I've edited my initial post in response to your replies. BTW - I do use external CSS file

Comment: "In regards to what the % stand for, it's viewport width, i.e. the number of pixels in the inner browser window, showing the HTML, nothing to do with your screen resolution" But greater the screen resolution, the more pixels will viewport contain?!

Comment: And if you keep your window on a 600px by 400px size? Not everyone has their browser window maximized, you know...

Comment: @Oded & All coders here: Please tell that the Default 100% body Width is Equal to How many Pixels ?

Comment: @user514892 - Think for a second. This will be different on different devices, and on the same device it will change if you resize the browser window. That question makes no sense.

Comment: "Yes, the CSS will be applied to the element containing it." I don't agree on the choice of words here. The CSS declaration will apply to the CSS selector(s) that define the width property, not on the containing element. The calculation of the width however is based on the width of the containing (parent) element which acts as a max width.

Answer (score 1):

The default width of `body` is 100%, but `html` is the parent container of `body`, so it will affect `body` in some circumstances if you're not aware of it.

Comment: hi, in case you find the time ... I've edited my initial post in response to your replies

Answer (score 1):

> “My screen resolution is set to 1024*768, and thus in my case the width of a `<body>` is 1024px?”

As Tor mentioned, the `<html>` element can have margin, borders and padding of its own.

In addition, the browser window’s scrollbars can take up some space too.

Comment: Under what conditions would <html> element have its own margin, borders and padding?

Comment: I may be remembering this wrong, but I think some browsers put a little border on the HTML element. I always tend to set margin, border and padding on <html> and <body> to zero.

Answer (score 1):

> A) I assume that when we use percentages, the percentage value refers to the width of the containing block?

It varies depending on the property the percentage is assigned to. For font-size, for example, it is the computed font-size of the parent element.

Padding is calculated based on the computed [width of the parent block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#value-def-padding-width) — even padding-top uses the width. (Remember, the width is the content width and excludes padding, borders and margins).

> B) What is the default width of a  element?

The default width of the body element is `auto` which is "Whatever space is left once margin, padding and borders have been taken into account". Since browsers have non-zero padding and/or margin there by default (which of the two depends on the browser), this is not 100%.

Comment: I assume by “browsers having non-zero padding…” you mean the body element has non zero padding and margin? Anyways, thanx for helping me